# Thought process for the following problem?

Tags: algorithms, arrays

We are given a 1-d array and we have to return  the smallest array attainable after removing all the continuous same numbers. We can only eliminate those numbers which repeat continuously more than or equal to 3 times.

So for eg. `[1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1]` should return `[1, 1]` i.e. first the elimination of `2`'s occuring three times and after its elimination there is `3` for four times at stretch. After eliminating `3`'s we are left with `1`'s which occur less than three times, so no elimination.

Similarly `[3,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,3]` should return `[3,1,3,2,3]`. Here we can jumble the eliminations in different ways but no order of eliminations can lead to an array less than in size than `[3,1,3,2,3]`.

The time complexity should have a tighter upper bound than $O(n^2)$.

I am thinking of this problem but I haven't been able to identify a specific technique for solving it. I am thinking of `hashing`, `graphs` and also `recursion` but till now I have failure tackling the order of eliminations as the eliminations can happen in random order. More than the solution I would like to know the technique and thought process walkthrough of this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "better than $O(n^2)$"? Do you mean $O(n^2)$, or $o(n^2)$? If the former, I would try dynamic programming.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I just mean it should have tighter upper bound than $O(n^2)$ i.e. $O(nlogn)$ or $O(n)$ would do.

Comment: Usually we denote your "better than $O(n^2)$" by $o(n^2)$.

Comment: You can proceed with your dynamic programming answer as I would be keen to get your explanation.

Comment: It was a suggestion for you, though.

Comment: Off late DP has been blurry due to less practice. It would be a refresher :)

Answer (score 1):

Using O(n) extra space, you need to record start for each run of same numbers. Scan the array linearly. Once you removed a run, you either continue previous run, or start a new one.

```
for i:
  if a[i] != a[i-1]:
    if run[x] - run[x-1] >= 3:
      x--
      // avoid copying the run into output array
    if a[run[x]] != a[i]:
      x++
    run[x] = i
```

On the second thought, you don't need the `run[]` array - only start the of current run. Once a run eliminated, you can check that previous run is at least 3 elements long in `O(1)` operations. You still need `O(n)` place to store the list of eliminated ranges, though.

Comment: I specifically mentioned that more than the solution I want the thought process and techniques involved in solving the problem. Either you explain how you got to the solution otherwise this is not a fitting answer for me.

Comment: I checked the second example - it flies. So, try to implement it or just perfrom the check again.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is badly explained. Try improving it.

Comment: Oh, boy, if you can't got it and need a help, try to be more polite next time

Comment: Here is a counterexample to the greedy approach: aaabbbaa. You should delete bbb first.